# C logging libraries

Tags: c, logging

What are the C logging API's out there?
Some of them I found are

1. [log4c](http://sourceforge.net/projects/log4c/)
2. [pantheios](http://www.pantheios.org/)
3. [lwl](http://home.gna.org/lwl/)

Is anyone aware of other loggers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

[syslog](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Syslog.html)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at Zlog. It's lightweight, thread-safe and easy to setup.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/HardySimpson/zlog)

Answer (score 3):

glib2 also has a good scalable logging API: [Glib message logging](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Message-Logging.html)

Comment: Would you care to add the URL?

Comment: http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.18/glib-Message-Logging.html

Answer (score 2):

With log4c you should have one good logging API.

Why do you need more?

A description can be found [here](http://log4c.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/*checkout*/log4c/log4c/doc/Log4C-DevelopersGuide.odt?revision=1.10).

Comment: LoL. yea..thats good enough for throwing a core dump...

Comment: Can you be more specific? When do you get a core dump? I don't think that log4c is the reason.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I did some digging and found that it was the autoconf and rpl_malloc issue. the rpl_malloc was giving a segfault.
I fixed it.
But now I need to learn how to use log4c and there is no documentation on how to use it.

Comment: Have you read the Log4C-DevelopersGuide.odt?

Comment: @Burkhard, I am using log4c for the first time. And I am having a hard time trying to find some documentation. Do you have any link for the developers guide? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used it in a while: I'd start here (http://log4c.sourceforge.net/) and since it is close to log4j, this (http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/docs/manual.html) might also help.