# application logging in a pure win32 project

Tags: c, windows, logging, winapi

In web development I've my own framework which uses a log file to help me in development and to monitor errors or production. This web framework, almost always running on *nix, uses a simple plain text as logfile, logrotate and tail.

Today I'm creating a win32 app, which will act as TCP/IP server (this is a desktop app but embed some services) and I need to log events in order to know when things goes bad (in production AND development, to debug while I'm creating it).

I remember MFC, which I had TRACE macro. That was fine to development debug. Are there something like TRACE in pure win32 development?

To production log, what's the best approach to event logging? Windows Event Log or simple plain text files? how can I rotate it in windows?

Thank you,
Daniel Koch

Comment: You can replace TRACE with your own C/C++ macros... as for which type of logging to do, it's really up to you - I've seen both.

Comment: The standard solution here is to use [Event Tracing for Windows (ETW)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/etw/event-tracing-portal). It's particularly helpful, when you need to get those diagnostics from a live, production service, as it can be enabled/disabled on the fly, and provides ways to access the diagnostics remotely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For development usually it's enough to use some `OutputDebugString` wrap like this:

```
inline void logA(const char* format, ...)
{
    char buf[1024];
    wvsprintfA(buf, format, ((char*)&format) + sizeof(void*));
    OutputDebugStringA(buf);
}

#define DEBUG_LOG_A(format, ...) logA( \
        "(#" BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE( __LINE__ ) ") "__FUNCTION__ " : " \
        format, __VA_ARGS__)
```

And [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) to watch it.

Comment: Nice function, but need I use this DebugView to see log or can I use console of Visual Studio? What about production mode?

Comment: @Daniel Koch : Yes out can use MSVS output window.

Comment: Abyx, thanks a lot! I'll use OutputDebugString in my own DEBUG_LOG macro to trace application in DEV mode. In production, I'll use a SQLite file which is better to export and use than ReportEvent (Event Log is too complex).

Answer (score 2):

[log4c](http://log4c.sourceforge.net/index.html) is the C version of the widely-used `log4j` framework (see log4cxx above, which is for C++).  You could certainly tailor this to output data wherever you wish.

It has to be compiled using GCC but once built you should be able to use the libs from a program compiled with the Microsoft toolchain.

[This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613919/c-logging-apis) covers some other C options.

Comment: Hi Steve, I liked log4c. But I don't know how to rotate it in a production enviroment. Do you know how? To development, I think I can follow Abyx's tip, to use OutputDebugString, that's fine.

Comment: When you say rotate, do you mean customize?  You can configure the library at runtime in Prod/Dev so that output goes only where you want.  The documentation is not great but the default config file in the download should be indicative.

Answer (score 0):

Back then, I successfully used [log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [ATL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Template_Library) in your project, I suggest you do so, if you're not frightened by a bit of C++ templates :-)

It's a quite lightweight library, but very usefull for basic operations, you can also decide to link statically to it, wich is cool when you don't want deployment issues.

And, back to the tracing question, it has an [ATLTRACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xkxyz08%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) macro that's quite helpful.

Comment: Thanks Simon, but I'm not going to use C++ here.

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to the development part, (equivalent to “TRACE”),  not only that it possible but you can set colors and font styles.
First, you call:

```
#include <conio.h>
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
```

To set the text color, I use:

```
inline void setcolor(int textcol, int backcol)
{
    if ((textcol % 16) == (backcol % 16))textcol++;
    textcol %= 16; backcol %= 16;
    unsigned short wAttributes = ((unsigned)backcol << 4) | (unsigned)textcol;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, wAttributes);
}
```

Then, just use wprintf() to display the text.
If you wish to clear the display area, just call:

```
system("cls");
```

Also refresh the display by calling:

```
void refresh()
{
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, L"CabinetWClass", NULL);
    while (hwnd != NULL)
    {
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, 41504, 0);
        hwnd = FindWindowEx(NULL, hwnd, L"CabinetWClass", NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"This is how you write formatted output to the Windows Console (assuming you understand the magic values, and can properly guess the missing details)"* is not an answer to the question: *"How do I implement monitoring, that can be used in a production environment?"*.

Comment: You probably misread the question. There is nothing here about monitoring but about logging and tracing.

Comment: *"I need to log events in order to know when things goes bad [...] in production"* - that's commonly called *monitoring*.

Comment: That's the background, not the question. He needs something similar to TRACE. Read carefully..

Comment: *"That was fine to development debug."* - And yet, they are looking for something that works in development **and** a production environment. This proposed answer assumes, that the calling process has a console attached. Not all processes do. The `TRACE` macro calls `OutputDebugStringW`, which doesn't have that requirement. The latter, too, is find in a development environment. Neither `TRACE` nor this proposed answer are helpful in a production environment. It's unclear how adding color to output to a potentially non-existent console is an answer to any question.

Comment: I edited my answer. It (like most of the other answers) addresses the first part of the question: “I remember MFC, which I had TRACE macro. That was fine to development debug. Are there something like TRACE in pure win32 development?”

Comment: `TRACE` writes to the debug log, whereas this proposed answer insists on writing to a console (that may not even be present). That's not useful.